# What is the shortcut to open the home folder in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: keyboard, gui, shortcuts, shortcut-keys

What is the shortcut to open the home folder in Ubuntu 20.04.2 lts?
I am new to Ubuntu.

Comment: Open *what* folder? If you want a quick action to the file manager, press the [Super] (Windows) key, type “fi” for Files, then hit [Enter] 

Comment: To open home folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you hit the window key and start typing it should find the file. You can then click on it to open.

Comment: Your answer was very useful, but Is there any other key like windows "WindowsKey+E"?

Comment: @JB.Thilipkumar https://superuser.com/questions/139959/is-there-a-shortcut-key-for-file-browser-equiv-of-wine This works in Kubuntu out of the box. You can add a custom short-cut in gnome under 20.04 as described in the linked answer relating to Ubuntu 18.04..